# Исправить js код на html странице

Tags: javascript, bitcoin

Хочу исправить код js для своих нужд - снять ограничение на автономном веб-архиве, которая создает brainwallet адреса. По умолчанию стоит требование фраза не менее 15 символов, а мне надо поменьше создать, пытался исправить, не получается. Сайт walletgenerator.net , репозиторий на гитхабе https://github.com/walletgeneratornet/WalletGenerator.net
Скорее всего все нужные исправления в одном скрипте (ninja.brainwallet.js), вот ее код:

```
ninja.wallets.brainwallet = {
    open: function () {
        document.getElementById("brainarea").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("brainpassphrase").focus();
        document.getElementById("brainwarning").innerHTML = ninja.translator.get("brainalertpassphrasewarning");
    },

    close: function () {
        document.getElementById("brainarea").style.display = "none";
    },

    minPassphraseLength: 15,

    view: function () {
        document.getElementById("brainerror").innerHTML = "";

        var key = document.getElementById("brainpassphrase").value.toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""); // trim white space
        document.getElementById("brainpassphrase").value = key;
        var keyConfirm = document.getElementById("brainpassphraseconfirm").value.toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""); // trim white space
        document.getElementById("brainpassphraseconfirm").value = keyConfirm;

        if (key == keyConfirm || document.getElementById("brainpassphraseshow").checked) {
            // enforce a minimum passphrase length
            if (key.length >= ninja.wallets.brainwallet.minPassphraseLength) {
                var bytes = Crypto.SHA256(key, { asBytes: true });
                var btcKey = new Bitcoin.ECKey(bytes);
                var bitcoinAddress = btcKey.getBitcoinAddress();
                var privWif = btcKey.getBitcoinWalletImportFormat();
                document.getElementById("brainbtcaddress").innerHTML = bitcoinAddress;
                document.getElementById("brainbtcprivwif").innerHTML = privWif;
                ninja.qrCode.showQrCode({
                    "brainqrcodepublic": bitcoinAddress,
                    "brainqrcodeprivate": privWif
                });
                document.getElementById("brainkeyarea").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("brainerror").innerHTML = ninja.translator.get("brainalertpassphrasetooshort");
                ninja.wallets.brainwallet.clear();
            }
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("brainerror").innerHTML = ninja.translator.get("brainalertpassphrasedoesnotmatch");
            ninja.wallets.brainwallet.clear();
        }
    },

    clear: function () {
        document.getElementById("brainkeyarea").style.visibility = "hidden";
    },

    showToggle: function (element) {
        if (element.checked) {
            document.getElementById("brainpassphrase").setAttribute("type", "text");
            document.getElementById("brainpassphraseconfirm").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("brainlabelconfirm").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("brainpassphrase").setAttribute("type", "password");
            document.getElementById("brainpassphraseconfirm").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("brainlabelconfirm").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
};
```

исправление `minPassphraseLength: 15` или удаление не помогает.

Пробовал убирать ряд строк, - не получилось, но я в коде практически ничего не понимаю:

```
`ninja.wallets.brainwallet = {
    open: function () {
        document.getElementById("brainarea").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("brainpassphrase").focus();
        document.getElementById("brainwarning").innerHTML = ninja.translator.get("brainalertpassphrasewarning");
    },

    close: function () {
        document.getElementById("brainarea").style.display = "none";
    },

    view: function () {
        document.getElementById("brainerror").innerHTML = "";

        var key = document.getElementById("brainpassphrase").value.toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""); // trim white space
        document.getElementById("brainpassphrase").value = key;
        var keyConfirm = document.getElementById("brainpassphraseconfirm").value.toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""); // trim white space
        document.getElementById("brainpassphraseconfirm").value = keyConfirm;

            var bytes = Crypto.SHA256(key, { asBytes: true });
            var btcKey = new Bitcoin.ECKey(bytes);
            var bitcoinAddress = btcKey.getBitcoinAddress();
            var privWif = btcKey.getBitcoinWalletImportFormat();
            document.getElementById("brainbtcaddress").innerHTML = bitcoinAddress;
            document.getElementById("brainbtcprivwif").innerHTML = privWif;
            ninja.qrCode.showQrCode({
                "brainqrcodepublic": bitcoinAddress,
                "brainqrcodeprivate": privWif
            });
            document.getElementById("brainkeyarea").style.visibility = "visible";

    },

    clear: function () {
        document.getElementById("brainkeyarea").style.visibility = "hidden";
    },

    showToggle: function (element) {
        if (element.checked) {
            document.getElementById("brainpassphrase").setAttribute("type", "text");
            document.getElementById("brainpassphraseconfirm").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("brainlabelconfirm").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("brainpassphrase").setAttribute("type", "password");
            document.getElementById("brainpassphraseconfirm").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("brainlabelconfirm").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
};`
```

Помогите снять ограничение вообще или убавить до минимума - одного символа например. Спасибо

Comment: `minPassphraseLength: 15,` Вам ни о чем не говорит?

Comment: @ddeadlink если бы вы внимательно прочитали вопрос, то увидели бы *исправление `minPassphraseLength: 15` или удаление не помогает*. Так что думаю, что говорит, но видать проблема в кеше или деплое.

Comment: А что вы сделали, после того как исправили `minPassphraseLength`?

Comment: Сорри, я чайник в html и js, после исправления `minPassphraseLength: 15`, я чистил куки и кеш в браузере и запускал страницу. А что надо? Может там надо вытереть лишнее в блоке, где `// enforce a minimum passphrase length` ? или вообще его убрать как-то. Мне не требуется никуда заливать этот код, мне нужно всего лишь локально запустить вебстраницу в браузере на компе.

Comment: Вы написали в вопросе, что Вам сейчас длина символов 15 и менее, а Вам нужно сделать "поменьше", после этого вы говорите, что поставили `minPassphraseLength: 15`. После этого я перестал Вам понимать

Comment: Я тоже недопонимаю о чем вы все твердите, я уже писал, что удаление вообще, как и например `minPassphraseLength: 1` вместо `minPassphraseLength: 15` не помогло...